# why apache not working?

Tags: php, laravel

I have already create one project in laravel that name pcu.sr.

and i also create one virtualehost same name of project.
and create one route look like:

```
Route::get('/',function(){
 return 'Hello Friends';
});
```

This route is properly work in virtualhost
but when i am create another route look like:

```
Route::get('users',function(){
 return 'this is a users view page';
});
```

and then after i open my browser and type look like...

1:pcu.sr this work but i type look like

2:pcu.sr/users it not work and browser display error look like..

> Not Found
>   The requested URL /users was not found on this server.
>   Apache/2.4.6 (Ubuntu) Server at theme.sr Port 80

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable Rewrite module in `httpd.conf`:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

This line should be without `#` at the beginning and you should restart your server after this change.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with some thing like this

```
Route::get('/users',function(){
 return 'this is a users view page';
});
```

Comment: I try it but it is not working browser display error as it is