# Laravel won't route except home directory

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have a fresh install with almost no changes and it will not accept any new routes. I have tried multiple things with the virtual hosts file, mostly what I found on other sites but nothing has worked.

I am able to get the default, but no other routes.

So this works:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
});
```

but this doesn't:

```
Route::get('test', function()
{
    return 'Hello;
});
```

Right now I have a `conf` file for apache that looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

#Host Name
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
DocumentRoot /path/to/our/public

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

<Directory /path/to/our/public>
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        Options -MultiViews
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I have no problem accessing the site, it loads and I get the welcome page from laravel but I can't do any other routing or anything. Permissions are all okay and I can change this route to anything I want.

Comment: what info you get for other urls than home page?

Comment: just a 404 page not found error

Comment: @eignhpants Laravel's 404 page, or your web server's standard 404 page?

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26501188/why-apache-not-working/26501294#26501294

Comment: standard browser 404 page

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek when I add that change the Apache servcer fails to restart.

Comment: have you tried `index.php/test` to see if the issue is with mod rewrite? If this works then we know that the routing in Laravel works and it is something in apache.

Comment: @dasper yes this worked. So yea, the problem must be apache.

Comment: The problem was solved by running through a post I linked to below, thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get it working by changing the AllowOverride on the rules for the `/var/www in my /etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file.

Original:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride none
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

New:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the error by following topics in the comments from my question.

Most expeccially [this link on the ReWrite engine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16899065/2091965) property in the `.haccess` file and [this linke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514990/laravel-4-all-routes-except-home-result-in-404-error/16864142#16864142) regarding changing the `httpd.conf` file (`apache2.conf` on my Apaache/Ubuntu system).